Why does `ConversationalRetrievalChain/RetrievalQA` include prompt in answer that cause recursive text growth?
I am building RAG Chatbot on my own data using langchain. There are a lot of guidelines how to do it, for example this one
Most of the guides recommend to use ConversationalRetrievalChain. However, I noticed that it recursively analyze previous texts multiple times, leading to a quadratic increase in the length of text with each new question. Is it expected behavior? How to fix this?
Minimal Reproducible Example
For simplicity, let's ignore embedder (assume that there is no relevant documents). So the base code will be next:
import gradio as gr
from langchain.chains import ConversationalRetrievalChain
from langchain_community.embeddings import HuggingFaceEmbeddings
from langchain_community.llms.huggingface_pipeline import HuggingFacePipeline
from langchain_core.vectorstores import InMemoryVectorStore
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM, pipeline

LLM_MODEL_NAME = 'meta-llama/Llama-3.2-1B-Instruct'  # can be any other model
EMBEDDER_MODEL_NAME = 'dunzhang/stella_en_1.5B_v5'  # doesn't matter here

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(LLM_MODEL_NAME)
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(LLM_MODEL_NAME)
llm_pipeline = pipeline(
    'text-generation',
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    max_new_tokens=256,
)
llm = HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=llm_pipeline)

# just mock of embedder and vector store
embedder = HuggingFaceEmbeddings(model_name=EMBEDDER_MODEL_NAME)
vector_store = InMemoryVectorStore(embedder)

retriever = vector_store.as_retriever()
chain = ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm(
    llm=llm,
    retriever=retriever,
    return_source_documents=True,
)


def predict(message: str, history: list[list[str]]) -> str:
    history = [tuple(record) for record in history]
    result = chain.invoke({
        'question': message,
        'chat_history': history,
    })
    return result['answer']


gr.ChatInterface(predict).launch()

When I run this code, the model recursively analyze the same part more and more times. This part is highlighted in the red box on the screen:

PS This behavior also happens in case of RetrievalQA chain
UPD I find similar issue in this Reddit post for RetrievalQA chain, but it doesn't have a useful answer
